# Matrix Multiplication Error in C

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have been working on some code to implement a discrete cosine transform using C. This is the code I am using for my matrix multiplication.

```
float Yt[8][8][4];
float Y8[8][8][4]={{{0.980785,-0.555570,0.555570 ...}}};
float A[8][8]={{0.707107,0.707107 ... }};

for(k=0;k<4;++k){
        for(i=0;i<8;++i){
            for(j=0;j<8;++j){
            Yt[i][j][k]=0;
            }}}

for(k=0;k<4;++k){
    for(i=0;i<8;++i){
         for(j=0;j<8;++j){
            for(l=0;l<8;++l){
                Yt[i][j][k]+=A[i][l]*Y8[l][j][k];
                }}}}
```

Y8 is the same 8x8 matrix, repeated 4 times.
My code successfully compiles and runs. However, the output that I receive is obviously incorrect. `Yt[i][j][k] for k=0,1,2,3` should all be the same value, but I end up with the correct values for k=0,1 and different values for k=2,3.

Can anyone see why I am getting incorrect values for the last two matrices?

Comment: Add `Yt[i][j][k] = 0.0` before `for(l=0;l<8;++l)`.

Comment: I would add some code to enforce that `Y8[][][1:3] == Y8[][][0]`, then try again. Just put it in the initialization loop of Yt: `Y8[i][j][k] = Y8[i][j][0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chux makes a good call about initializing they value of `Yt` before using it. You might do something like this:

```
for(k=0;k<4;++k){
  for(i=0;i<8;++i){
    for(j=0;j<8;++j){
      double temp = 0.0;
      for(l=0;l<8;++l){
        temp += A[i][l]*Y8[l][j][k];
      }
      Yt[i][j][k] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow the compiler to use a register for the accumulation, then access `Yt` (with its three indexing operations) just once.

Comment: I do initialize Yt beforehand, just left it out of my OP. And Y8 is only the same three times because I am using it to troubleshoot at the moment. Y8 is a matrix of values from an image

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `Y8` is the same four times? What if you modified the code to `Yt[i][j][k]+=A[i][l]*Y8[l][j][0];` - it should still be wrong if your matrix multiplication is wrong. If it suddenly is right, then `Y8` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Ran it like you suggested, and all values came out as expected. I guess I need to take a closer look at `Y8`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `Yt[i][j][k]`.

I suspect this would be done as below

```
for(j=0;j<8;++j){
  Yt[i][j][k] = 0.0;
  for(l=0;l<8;++l){
    Yt[i][j][k] += A[i][l]*Y8[l][j][k];
  }
}
```

... or in its declaration.  Something like `double Yt[8][8][4] = { 0.0 };`

Comment: You get the +1 because it was your idea in the first place… Declaration is OK if you only use it once - initializing inside loop is more robust. I prefer the use of a temp variable (faster without need for clever compiler)